# Convert text date format to number date format

Tags: date, format, libreoffice

I have stored some data entrys in a CSV file in following Format:
`Thu Jul 28 08:42:33 GMT+01:00 2016`
 and need to convert it to just a time stamp (eg. `h:m:s`). How can I quickly and easily do this?

Comment: Using what programming language? Or is this sql loader? You need to be way more specific in order to get adequate help.

Comment: A little more information might be helpful. While some of us (not me) are god-like geniuses, none of us are mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a text date in a cell to a serial number, you use the DATEVALUE function. Then you copy the formula, select the cells that contain the text dates, and use Paste Special to apply a date format to them. Select a blank cell and verify that its number format is General.

Comment: Can I do this using LIbreOffice?

Comment: Using LibreOffice, `DATEVALUE` on the time stamp gives "Err:502".  However I will not downvote this answer, because the `libreoffice` tag was added *after* this answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

If the size is fixed, then assuming the string is in A1:

```
=MID(A1,12,8)
```

The result can then be converted to an actual time value using [TIMEVALUE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/TIMEVALUE).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a simple call to a single function would extract the substring you want, since it begins at a specific offset and only runs for eight characters (two hh plus colon plus two mm plus colon plus two ss).